# CoreData objectID is always the same after save

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Here is my issue. I create a coreData NSMAnagedObject, save it and it always create a new object with the same objectID ... Which doesn't make any sens to me as i thought objectID would be unique. I must be missing something as big as an elephant in the room but I can't see it ...

Here is my portion of code:

```
- (Conversation *) saveImagesToCore:(NSData *)userImage andOtherImage:(NSData *)otherImage {

NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];

Message *topMessage = [self saveImageToCore:otherImage
                                 andCloudID:self.otherCloudIDsmall
                                    andUser:_friendShaker];
Message *bottomMessage = [self saveImageToCore:userImage
                                    andCloudID:_userCloudID
                                       andUser:_currentUser];

NSSet *messages = [NSSet setWithArray:@[topMessage, bottomMessage]];


NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Conversation"
                                                     inManagedObjectContext:moc];

Conversation *newConversation = (Conversation *)[[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entityDescription
                                                         insertIntoManagedObjectContext:moc];

newConversation.dateStarted = [NSDate date];
newConversation.isHost = [NSNumber numberWithBool:_currentUserIsCalling];
newConversation.user = (User *) _friendShaker.userCoreData;
[newConversation addMessage:messages];

NSError *error = nil;

if (![newConversation.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to save managed object context.");
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Conversation saved *******");
    NSLog(@"Conversation ID %@",[newConversation objectID]);

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:newConversation forKey:@"conversation"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ConversationSaved" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
}

return (Conversation *) newConversation;}
```

Thanks for any help. I'm going crazy.

Here is a printout of the newConversation object:

```
<Conversation: 0x16758cd0> (entity: Conversation; id: 0x165073b0 <x-coredata://E31BE071-9ED6-4624-8440-2DC619535A00/Conversation/p7> ; data: {
allowShareOther = 0;
allowShareSelf = 0;
dateLastModified = nil;
dateStarted = "2015-07-05 15:03:24 +0000";
isHost = 1;
message =     (
    "0x165b1780 <x-coredata://E31BE071-9ED6-4624-8440-2DC619535A00/Message/p14>",
    "0x165caa00 <x-coredata://E31BE071-9ED6-4624-8440-2DC619535A00/Message/p13>"
);
preview = nil;
type = nil;
user = "0x16687110 <x-coredata://E31BE071-9ED6-4624-8440-2DC619535A00/User/p3>";})
```

You will notice my problem: The newConversation ObjectID is actually the user ObjectID. So everytime I create a conversation, it has the user's ObjectID.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being obtuse, but I can't see the problem.  What in the `newConversation` printout shows that its `objectID` is actually the user `objectID`?

Comment: That right! I was reading the wrong way the ObjectID.

Answer (score 0):

Try "refreshing" the objectID:

```
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator =  [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] persistentStoreCoordinator];
NSURL *uriRep = [newConversation.objectID URIRepresentation];
NSManagedObjectID *realID = [coordinator managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:uriRep];

NSLog(@"Conversation ID %@",realID);
```

Comment: Same result. I know that as long as the NSManaged object is not saved, it has a temporary ObjectID. But it should create a new entity everytime with the same ObjectID.